# How to show user info from the database in profile using angular postgres and node? My code doesn't work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, routes, sequelize.js

I have no idea why my code doesn 't work and would be happy about some help. Also, it seems that my backend route is never '
hit '- the route for all user routes is 
    api/user and instead of hitting   api/user/:id it goes into api/user..ANY help so much appreciated!!!

My backend route in node.js:

```
router.get('/:id', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('great', req.user.id)
        // check that user is current user or Admin
    if (!req.user.isAdmin && req.user.id != req.params.id) {
        res.status(403).send('Forbidden');
        return
    }
    User.findById(req.params.id)
        .then(function(user) {
            res.send(user)
        }).catch(next)
})
Angular factory: var baseUrl = '/api/users/';
var getData = res => res.data;
UserFactory.fetchOne = function(id) {
return $http.get(baseUrl + id)
    .then(function(response) {
        return response.data;
    });
}
```

Angular state for the profile:

```
app.config(function($stateProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('user', {
        url: '/users/:id',
        templateUrl: 'js/profile/profile.html',
        controller: 'ProfileCtrl'

    });
});
```

My controller:

```
app.controller('ProfileCtrl', function($scope, UserFactory,
    $stateParams, $log) {
    UserFactory.fetchOne($stateParams.id)
        .then(function(user) {
            $scope.user = user;
        })
})
```

Part of him for the profile:

```
< div class = "col-md-3 sidebar" >
< h3 > Welcome {
    {
        user.firstName
    }
} {
    {
        user.lastName
    }
} < /h3> < /div>
```

Comment: api/users or api/user? Whe need to see more of the NodeJS routing part. Where do you define the route for api/user(s)?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I require my routes in index.js :     app.use('/api', require('./routes')); then in my routes folder I require the different path (for example router.use('/users', require('./users')) all my routes work- its just really the one with /:id that doesn't seem to work or I was thinking maybe the mistake is in my factories $http request- that for some reason I don't request /api/users/:id but only /api/users

Comment: also in the url it says /api/user/undefined - wich means the id is never being 'transmitted'

Comment: then you need to log $stateParams in the controller to see if the property id exists there or if it's undefined.

Comment: Im not sure how to log it in the fronted?! But it seems undefined because im getting http://localhost:1337/api/users/undefined

Comment: in the controller, just before the call to the factory, console.log($stateParams.id); or alert($stateParams.id); You can also try to hardcode the id (use id id that you know exists) and see you get a response.

Comment: Okay I did the alert and it alerts nothing (its empty) and also put in a few console.log and the only one logged is the one I put into catch -   .catch(function (err) {
    alert($stateParams.id); 
    console.error('blaaaa',$stateParams.id)
  });